# vsock resource temporarily unavailable?

Tags: networking

I cannot seem to figure this one out, but the issue is when I try to serve a vsock connection on a given port, it keeps returning resource temporarily unavailable. Even though it says temporarily, it loops forever. Does anyone have an inkling to what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with usage of an earlier kernel which used different mode and dev when using mknod. In earlier Linux kernel version, they would allocate a random dev value. However, later kernels will mknod with 10, 241.